# Comparing the latest and second latest order dates by user

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to see the latest and second latest odrers of users who made an order using a code 'MO1 + M01' by each user and filtering by the number of datediff that is less than or equal to 365 days.

My below query seems to over exclude and returns no values:

Note: alot of the emails are either NULL or blank due to retail ad hoc transactions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT oh.[UID Email], c.[Offer], a2.[LatestOrderDate], a2.[OrderCount], b2.[SecondOrderDate], b2.[SecondOrderCount],
DATEDIFF(DAY,a2.[LatestOrderDate],b2.[SecondOrderDate]) Gap_Days
FROM [RBI Order Header] oh

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT [UID Email], [Order Date] [LatestOrderDate], [OrderCount]
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER(ORDER BY [Contact Order Count] DESC) AS 'OrderCount',
    [UID Email], 
    [Order Date]
    FROM [RBI Order Header]
    WHERE [UID Email] LIKE '%@%') a
WHERE OrderCount = 1
GROUP BY [UID Email], [Order Date], [OrderCount]) a2 
ON oh.[UID Email] = a2.[UID Email]

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT [UID Email], [Order Date] [SecondOrderDate], [SecondOrderCount]
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER(ORDER BY [Contact Order Count] DESC) AS 'SecondOrderCount',
    [UID Email], 
    [Order Date]
    FROM [RBI Order Header]
    WHERE [UID Email] LIKE '%@%') b
WHERE SecondOrderCount = 2
GROUP BY [UID Email], [Order Date], [SecondOrderCount]) b2 
ON oh.[UID Email] = b2.[UID Email]

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(dl.[Offer No_],3) [Offer], dl.[Order No_] FROM [Rapha].dbo. [Staging Discount Line] dl
WHERE (dl.[Offer No_] LIKE 'MO1%' OR 
   dl.[Offer No_] LIKE 'M01%')) c
ON oh.[Posted Document No_]=c.[Order No_] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI

WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,a2.[LatestOrderDate],b2.[SecondOrderDate]) >= 365

GROUP BY oh.[UID Email], a2.[LatestOrderDate], b2.[SecondOrderDate], [Offer], DATEDIFF(DAY,a2.[LatestOrderDate],b2.[SecondOrderDate]), a2.[OrderCount], b2.[SecondOrderCount]
ORDER BY Gap_Days
```

Comment: Your query seems way more complicated than necessary.  However, without sample data and desired results, it really isn't possible to figure out what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out that final where clause;

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, a2.[LatestOrderDate], b2.[SecondOrderDate]) >= 365
```

Do you return any data now?

You mention that a lot of the emails are either NULL or blank and this field is what you're joining on, have you read up on three valued logic recently?

Answer (score 0):

your query is too complicated to debug and wrongly written.Rewrite your query using CTE.

Secondly you have so many distinct and group by.Obviously we need to see how table are populated with real data to find root cause of distinct.

My query is not exact,i have just tried to demonstrate,how to use CTE

```
;With CTE as
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER(ORDER BY [Contact Order Count] DESC) AS rn,
    [UID Email], 
    [Order Date]
    FROM [RBI Order Header]
    WHERE [UID Email] is not null
)
,CTE1 AS
(SELECT  oh.[UID Email], c.[Offer], a2.[Order Date] as [LatestOrderDate], a2.rn as [OrderCount], b2.[Order Date] as [SecondOrderDate], b2.rn as [SecondOrderCount],
DATEDIFF(DAY,a2.[Order Date],b2.[Order Date]) Gap_Days
FROM [RBI Order Header] oh
LEFT JOIN CTE a2 ON oh.[UID Email] = a2.[UID Email]
LEFT JOIN CTE b2 ON oh.[UID Email] = b2.[UID Email]
LEFT JOIN [Rapha].dbo. [Staging Discount Line] dl ON oh.[Posted Document No_]=d1.[Order No_] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI
where a2.rn=1 and b2.rn=1
AND (dl.[Offer No_] LIKE 'MO1%'  OR dl.[Offer No_] LIKE 'M01%') 
)

-- select * from cte //you can check here if you are getting correct output without using distinct
select * from  CTE1 where Gap_Days >= 365
```